# add rows in rich:datatable without erasing the typed lines

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Good Morning!
I am using a rich: extendedDataTable (JSF 1.2) and adding rows, however when I add a new row, the information I typed in the other rows are deleted.
I wonder if there is any way for just the lines to be added without deleting the data I filled out?

follow below code

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Adicionar" reRender="gridList" action="#{managed$EvpessSessionBean.addPessoas}" ajaxSingle="true"/>

<rich:extendedDataTable height="480px" id="gridList" rows="15" selectionMode="single" value="#{managed$EvpessSessionBean.pessoasLista}" var="listPessoas" width="890px" >

<rich:column label="Codigo" width="50px">
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="Codigo"/>
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{listPessoas.codpessoa}" />
</rich:column>

<rich:column label="Nome" width="290px">
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="Nome"/>
</f:facet>
<h:inputText value="#{listPessoas.nome}" style="width: 100%" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();"/>
```

```
</rich:extendedDataTable>
<rich:datascroller align="center" for="gridList" id="sc2" maxPages="20"/>
```

The Add button does the following ...

```
private List<Evpess> pessoasLista;

//Getter e Setter de pessoasLista...

public void addPessoas() {        
 Evpess p = new Evpess();        
 p.setCadacodigo(new Uccada());
 p.setCodmovisocial(new Evmoso());
 p.setEmprcod(new Eoempr(1));
 pessoasLista.add(p);            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit your dataTable content to your managed bean, so the values could be preserved.
Add `execute="gridList"` to your `a4j:commandButton`.